# Setting a value and reloading a page with that new value in a single click php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page I am making using html and php. I want to have a series of buttons at the top (currently just words as links) that sets a variable, then reloads the page with that variable. I am struggling to figure out how to do this. My past experience has been with search forms that require selections to be made then a submit button to be pressed, but I want it all to happen with a single click. Currently it looks like this:

My main page has:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['pageName'])) {
        $pageName = $_GET['pageName'];
        if ($pageName == "") {$pageName = "Home";}
    }
    else {
        $pageName = "Home";
    }
    include "head.php";
?>

// Additional code here

<?php
    include "$pageName.php";
?>
```

Then a header bar contains:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a style="font-size: 24px;" href="/My Website?pageName=Home">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a style="font-size: 24px;" href="/My Website?pageName=Page1">Page1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a style="font-size: 24px;" href="/My Website?pageName=Page2">Page2</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a style="font-size: 24px;" href="/My Website?pageName=Page3">Page3</a></li>
```

Each page is then saved as its own file for easier editing.

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-header-inner"><h1 class="entry-title">HEADER</h1></div>
</header>
    
<div class="post-inner thin">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p class="body"><!--MAIN CONTENT--></p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div><!-- .post-inner -->
```

What I want is the "Page2" button to simply change the $pageName variable to "Page2" and the page then be reloaded with that variable. What I am doing now functionally works, but I would like to know if what I want to do is possible, and what kind of functions I would need to use.

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is supposed to be here. If you want those links to _look_ like “buttons”, then you should format them according to your wishes using CSS. (_Real_ button elements should not be used to implement navigation - that is what links _are for_.)

Comment: Currently my code gets the $pageName variable from the address bar. I would like to know if there is a method to change the variable and reload the page without using the address bar at all.

Comment: Why, what would be the point of that? You’d only be _decreasing_ the usability of your site - bookmarking, or sharing specific pages on social media for example would become hard to impossible for the people using your site.

Comment: I am aware of that, but it would be useful in various other circumstances. Being able to click the button and have it affect the page in a defined way.

This specific example is just a practice example.

Comment: You can of course submit parameters via POST using a form, and then on the server side decide whatever you want to do next, based on those parameters. Or use AJAX to make requests in the background, and then insert the received content into the current document.

Comment: Is Client Side Navigation What You Are Searching For?

Comment: @AdisonMasih That actually looks exactly like what I'm looking for. The example I am looking at right now is literally exactly what I'm asking for here, in fact! Thanks for directing me to this. It kind of looks like I'm reaching the end of capabilities for just html and php and will actually have to learn js now. >.<

Comment: @TamiJo if you wanna learn js and want to implement cliend-side navigation, I will suggest you to learn React Or Vue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into both of those (unless I find out later it's just a thing called "React or Vue") when I've finished up on this project. (Y)